# jquery a.now - IE8 bug

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8

I'm having a problem with IE8 and jQuery. Precisely, the script breaks at this line:

```
a.elem.style[a.prop]=a.now+a.unit
```

I'm using jQuery v1.7.2 from http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js

You can see the error / website at this URL: http://www.melisayavas.com/gallery/

Is there a workaround this issue?

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do ?

Comment: What are the steps to raise this error? I see only a couple markup issues on the page, but no JS errors.

Comment: The error could be that `a` is null, that `elem` is null, that `a.elem.style` is null or doesn't have a member named as the value of `a.prop` or that setting it to `a.now+a.unit` is somehow problematic. I'm guessing that `a.elem.style` doesn't have a member named `a.prop` and that `a.prop` is a value such as `className` which is `cssClass` in IE, or `cssFloat` which is `styleFloat` in IE. Also, the code you've pasted is not making use of any part of jQuery.

Comment: If you are going to use jQuery then why not use jQuery? `$(a.elem).css(a.prop, a.now + a.unit);`

Comment: @DavidHedlund - The code posted is *part* of (minified) jQuery. George - Try using an unminified jQuery so you can see what's actually throwing the error.

Comment: @James: oh, the pasted line of code is from within the jQuery library itself? I hadn't realized, that's even less helpful than I could've imagined.

Comment: @DavidHedlund - Yeah, it's from the minified script (took me a while to notice, had to go through every script included in the OPs linked page searching for `a.now` until I found it in jQuery). I can't find what it would correspond to in the unminified source.

Comment: I had this issue with slideDown in IE8 with an element that I added to the dom on page load and subsequently called hide() on before the slideDown happened. "a.now" is NaN which throws an error. He is likely having the same issue but I couldn't figure out how he is causing the issue on his site.

Comment: I believe this to be a bug with jQuery where they aren't checking if a.Now is NaN before using it. The work around (besides editing the jQuery core code) is to explicitly set the margin on the element that you are calling slideToggle/slideDown/slideUp on. Of course if that is what you are doing. I can't figure out what you were actually trying to do.